# Sign in with Twitter and Security for a Zend Framework App

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to replicate the functionality i've seen on a couple of sites:

- http://todaslistas.heroku.com
- http://endor.se

The idea is you sign up and log in with Twitter using Oauth. Once you have authed the app at twitter you then return to their site and they keep you logged in. In the case of each one they obviously base this on cookies as i can return to the site after closing my browser and i am still logged in. This seems inherently insecure, what are they doing here to maintain the login?

I will be using Zend Framework but i guess that doesnt really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using cookies. Tho you should encrypt the cookeis on server-side, so that a user cannot manipulate its value.

Comment: in the case where you had - for example - an email address and an accessToken from Oauth then what would you recommend given that it would be necessary to encrypt and decrypyt?

Comment: can you recommend a good Zend Framework way of handling this?

Comment: There's nothing built-in in ZF for that purpose, but I wrote a small class in my blog to handle it: http://site.svn.dasprids.de/trunk/application/library/App/Cookie.php

Comment: or just an example of its usage?

Comment: Nope, there isn't, just call App_Cookie::setBlowfishSecret('your-secret'); and then App_Cookie::setEncrypt($key, $value);

Comment: where would it usually sit within a ZF MVC project - in the library?

Comment: Excatly, just see where I placed it.